# Why in Aashadamaasa and Dhanurmaas no auspicious things happens?

Tags: belief, rituals

Why in Aashadamaasa and Dhanurmaas no auspicious things happens? People follow some rituals during these time by not doing any auspicious functions. All business, marriages, home construction stops or they will not take any initiatives by this time. Can someone give a clear reason about this?

Comment: why downvote, and why it doesn't belong to Hindu who has suggested to close this question. Before downvoting, please specify reason?

Comment: Seems someone down voted bcz scientific speculation Qs are considered off topic here...pls edit the Q and remove scientific part...also it seems you have already considered them bad practice...

Comment: Now ur Q seems valid one... these months are set apart **for worship**... **to avoid any distraction**, marriages and other such functions are not performed... Also such practices are not widely followed by all, they vary from sect to sect and in diff geographical locations...for example marriages don't happen between Dev Shyani Ekadashi (June/July) - Dev Uthani Ekadashi (Oct/Nov) in North while can happen in South...

Comment: Usually, Ashadamaasa comes in August, so wife and husband won't meet in August. See the reason is August + 9 months = May, which is not good for newborns during summer time, so people avoid Ashaadamaasa. There may be other reasons also.

Comment: @user2225190 that's another custom...they keep newly wedded girl at her parents home irrespective of whether she got married in Aug, July, June, May...so it might not be the strong reason...also this custom is not common every where...in my side she has to be stay away with her mother in law and that also in Savan and not in Ashad...